# Bootstrap 3 modal bug?

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap

Использую версию 3.3.4, т.е. последнюю на данный момент. Проблема с модальными окнами, код

```
.ajax({
...
success: function (data)
{
  $('#modal').modal('hide');
  $('#success').modal('show');
}
})
```

Проблема в том что когда закрывается первое окно, и открывается второе, страница уезжает куда-то влево, в общем едет верстка. Если вызывать их по отдельности, то все ок, а вместе никак не могу заставить их работать.

Для первого есть `button`, т.е. `#modal` открывается по клику на кнопку, для #success только само модальное окно, без кнопки. Заметил, что при вызове

```
$('#success').modal('show');
```

К `body` не добавляется класс `modal-open` и т.д. Где я ошибся ?

Comment: Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос нужно видеть ваш HTML код